# Initializing map in struct

Tags: go

I am getting this [image: error] when I try to initialize a map in a struct. Here's the code:

```
//some code above
            storageNodes[id].blocks = make(map[int64]Block)//error here
            storageNodes[id].blocks[0] = generateBlockOfRandomFiles()
//some code below
//in a separate file
type StorageNode struct {
    *Node
    blocks map[int64]Block
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It says separate files, are they in the same package?

Comment: Show the definition of the `storageNodes` variable

Comment: [Please…](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/720999).

Comment: You asked this before. `storageNodes[id]` is not addressable. Change the declaration to use a pointer, or use `v:=storageNodes[id]; v.block[0]=generate...; storageNodes[id]=v`

Answer (score 0):

Direct assignment to non-pointer map values is illegal in Go.

```golang
type Node struct{ /* ... */ }

type Block struct{ /* ... */ }

type StorageNode struct {
    *Node
    blocks map[int64]Block
}

// ...

storageNodes := map[int]StorageNode{123: {}}
storageNodes[123].blocks = map[int64]Block{987: {}} // illegal
```

---

Use pointers:

```golang
storageNodes := map[int]*StorageNode{123: {}}
storageNodes[123].blocks = map[int64]Block{987: {}}
fmt.Println(storageNodes[123].blocks) // block 987 is present
```

Or, use temporary variable and re-assign once modified:

```golang
storageNodes := map[int]StorageNode{123: {}}

sn := storageNodes[123]              // read
sn.blocks = map[int64]Block{987: {}} // modify
storageNodes[123] = sn               // write back to map

fmt.Println(storageNodes[123].blocks) // block 987 is present
```